# Error while assigning xml node value in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm assigning a value to xml node.
That value is computed using Join-Path

This doesn't work:

```
$xml.root.element = Join-Path "d:\" $path
```

It's throwing this error:

Cannot set "element" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.

And this works fine:

```
$xml.root.element = (Join-Path "d:\" $path).ToString()
```

I thought that maybe Join-Path returns something other than string but

```
$a = Join-Path "d:\" $path
$b = (Join-Path "d:\" $path).ToString()
$a.GetType()
$b.GetType()
```

Both are String !!!

What's going on here?

Comment: Does this work? `$xml.root.element = (Join-Path "d:\" $path)`

Comment: To answer my own question: no it doesn't. My guess is that while assigning a value to the element, it starts assigning right away, and Join-Path is not a string. You need to make sure that what's right of the assignment are evaluated first. You have found one way, by using the ToString method. Another way is like this: `$xml.root.element = "$(Join-Path "d:\" $path)"`. In fact, we could get my first example to work by using `[string](Join-Path "d:\" $path)`. This way we are explicitly telling PowerShell that what's evaluated should be a string.